# Writing IntelliJ Scala Plugin Plugins?

Tags: java, scala, plugins, intellij-idea

Given that Scala support is itself a plugin in intellij, is there any way of writing intellij plugins leveraging the existing Scala functionality?

Things like support for parsing Scala, getting an AST, traversing the class/trait hierarchy, etc. should already be a part of the scala plugin, and I was wondering if I could make use of all these niceties from the get-go without having to redo it all myself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962925/can-i-get-ast-from-live-scala-code

Comment: The plugin is opensource. Just find them on GitHub or wherever they host. I don't think that Scala plugin itself has a plugin support, but  you can definitely extend it

Comment: I know they're open source; I was wondering if, in a moment of inspiration, I had some brilliant new feature I wanted to add that needed Scala language support, I had any option other than forking the plugin. Forking things is always pretty extreme and brings a huge pile of downsides I'd rather avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible since Intellij plugins can depend on each other

See e.g. http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7080 and http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=5007